# How do you create a typed Bean generating Factory?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I am trying to create a factory that can create typed Beans capable of being autowired by Spring for N types. Each type has 3 to 4 typed Beans that need to be defined and the config is growing more than I want to maintain by hand. Below is what I have so far:

```
    @Configuration
    public class ConfigurationFactory implements BeanFactoryAware {

        private static final String FOO_NAME = "{0}Foo";
        private static final String BAR_NAME = "{0}Bar";

        private final List<Class<?>> types = Arrays.asList(
            Cat.class,
            Dog.class,
            Horse.class,
            ... );

        private ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory;

        @Override
        public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

            configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void createBeans() {

            for (final Class<?> type : types) {
               createFooBeans(type);
               createBarBeans(type);
               ...
            }
        }

        private void createFooBeans(Class<?> type) {

            configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(
                MessageFormat.format(FOO_NAME, type.getName()),
                Foo.runtimeConstruct(type));
        }

        private void createBarBeans ...

    }

    @Component
    public class Foo<T> {

        public Foo(Class<T> type) {}

        public static <T> Foo<T> runtimeConstruct(Class<T> type) {
            return new Foo<>(type);
        }

        ...
    }
```

I am running into

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
```

So the autowiring for classes referencing the typed Beans doesn't appear to be working. I am not sure if this is caused by the types not getting set correctly because what I am attempting isn't possible with Java's runtime type erasure, or some issue with the BeanFactoryAware that I am missing.

Any Ideas?